# MySQL query equivalent in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for help from someone who is expert on Mongodb Development.
Below is My MySQL query :

```
select column_1,column_2,group_concat(column3 order by column4 asc ) as data_1 , group_concat(column5 order by column4 asc) as data_2 
from table_name 
where  column4>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
group by column_1,column_2
```

Basically I want data for past 15 minutes and group concat column data based on group by certain columns.
Please help me get through this query.

Below is the sample data stored in Mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6364fd1ae855d15c22632077"),
    "column3" : 1,
    "column_1" : 123456789,
    "column5" : "xyz",
    "source" : 1,
    "column_2" : NumberLong("22116755"),
    "column4" : ISODate("2022-11-04T11:51:55Z")
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit edited the question with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { column4: { $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 15) } } },
   { $sort: { column4: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { column_1: "$column_1", column_2: "$column_2" },
         data: { $push: { data_1: "$column3", data_2: "$column5" } },
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: ["$_id", "$data"] } }
])
```

Comment: its saying  : 

2022-11-04T19:01:42.889+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
 "code" : 40324,
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$replaceWith'"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:403:5
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1212:12
@(shell):1:1

Comment: See [$replaceWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/): *New in version 4.2*

Comment: Hi @Wernfried Domscheit Any alternatives ?  We are running on Mongo version 3.6.3

Comment: Did you read the doc? It says *"The `$replaceWith` is an alias for `$replaceRoot`"* - `$replaceRoot` was introduced long time ago! Sometimes I am really surprised how lazy people can be.

Comment: Apologies I didnt read the doc at that point of time !